# A naive question about "random" probability distributions

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So I've come up with this idea, which may be mathematically unprecise, but it goes as follows.

**Example:** Suppose you have a random variable $X$ taking values in the interval $[-1,1]$. Then, say, instead of a definite probability density $f(x)$ we have two different distributions $g$ and $h$ of the variable $X$. The probability that $X=x$ is the result of choosing either $g$ or $h$ by a toss of a coin and then taking the value of the corresponding density at the point $x$. The function $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2} (g(x)+h(x))$$ seems to be resulting probability density function of $X$.

Analogously, one can have a finite number $n$ of density functions, then assign $n$ different probabilities, one for each of then, and the result will be the probability density function of the combined different probabilities.

**Now the question.** Take the space $S$ of every **continuous** function from the interval $I=[-1,1]$ to the positive real axis, such that the integral of every function in this space $S$ in the interval $I$ equals one. Now define a random variable $X$, the value of which is taken in the following manner. First you pick a function $f$, belonging to $S$, completely at random, i. e., the probability of taking $f$ is the same as taking any other function. Then, in this case, the probability density of $X=x$ is just $f(x)$.

The problem: is there a "resulting probability distribution" as given in the first example, of the above process (taking at random a function and then taking the value of this function at a point $x$)? One can see such resulting function as the "expected" or "mean" function in the space $S$, with respect to a uniform probability distribution.

Again, I don't know if this heuristic construction is precise mathematically, neither, if it is, if this possess an interesting answer. I suspect the most reasonable answer should be the uniform density $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. I appreciate any comments in this question!

Comment: If you're going to pick a density funtion at random, then there's some probability distribution on that space of functions, i.e. for some suitable set of density functions, the probability that the chosen density is in that set is specified by the distribution.  If you specify such a distribution, then your question will have an answer.

Comment: What @MichaelHardy said, plus a sigma-algebra on the space S of nonnegative continuous functions on [-1,1] with integral 1.

Comment: So, isn't saying that, for instance, "every continuous function has the same probability" sufficient to get a unique, as @MichaelHardy says, probability distribution on that space of functions? If it is not suffiecient, what more has to be specified? I know barely nothing of measure theory, so I appreciate any reference that touches this question, or a similar one.

Comment: It is not sufficient.  Every continuous probability distribution assigns probability exactly $0$ to every point.  So merely saying each of them has probability $0$ does not determine the probability distribution.